# Providing system properties via command line with dot in the name in Gradle

Tags: gradle, properties

We are migrating our project from Maven to Gradle. Our CI uses system properties like `-Dwebdriver.type=firefox` to set certain behaviour thus we don't want to hardcode such props in `gradle.properties` file etc. Is there a way to provide a system property with a dot in the name using command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following:

**build.gradle**:

```
logger.lifecycle("some.property ${System.properties['some.property']}")
```

with:

```
gradle -Dsome.property=lol
```

It should give you the expected output.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work like `systemProperty "webdriver.type", "firefox"` defined in the build script and that is the problem

Comment: @MikołajMański could you please provide your `build.gradle` script? The problem is probably the fact that with `-D` you do pass the properties for the script itself - these properties should transferred forward.